# Is it possible to insert(not update) a field name as variable in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Im trying to insert a embedded document in mongodb for a meteor project.

```
'submit form' : function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var query=document.getElementsByClassName("twilioProcessorsms")[0].value;
  ChoiceList.insert({
  sms: esms,
  query: {
  accountSID: accsid,
  authToken: token,
  phoneNumber: phno}  
  });
```

I am trying to have the "query" as a variable. But it considers query as a string.I dont want to achieve this with an update. Pls help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
'submit form' : function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var query=document.getElementsByClassName("twilioProcessorsms")[0].value;
  
  var valueToInsert = {
    sms: esms
  };
  valueToInsert[query] = {
    accountSID: accsid,
    authToken: token,
    phoneNumber: phno}  
  };
  
  ChoiceList.insert(valueToInsert);
```

Comment: The variable query is just a string.Example , query="XXXX" ,not a JSON object